# data returns as undefined on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Story() {
  let { id } = useParams();
  const pin = useSelector(state => state.pins.pin);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userid = 2
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPin(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid" >

     <Upvote pin={pin.upvotes} userid={userid} />

    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function Upvote ({pin, userid}) {
  ///pin.filter(a => a.id === userid)
  return <div>test<div/>
}
```

pin would be undefined at first render. I tried doing an if statement in Upvote. not sure if that is the right way

```
if(pin)
   ///filter
```

Comment: Surely, you can add {pin && <Upvote .... />}

Comment: comes out as undefined at first when i try to filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably because the initial state of `pin` is undefined, or pin comes from a fetch operation, which is asynchronous.

What you can do is to [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) your child `Upvote` component only if `pin` is defined.

```
return (
  <div className="container-fluid" >
    {pin && pin.upvotes && <Upvote pin={pin.upvotes} userid={userid} />}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: @Xzeta I have updated my code. Try `pin && pin.upvotes` instead. In addition, is `upvotes` an array?

Comment: in that case, the condition i used should be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
{pin && <Upvote pin={pin.upvotes} userid={userid} />}
```

To only render the component when pin is not undefined. Alternatively you may want to have default values you can use when pin isn't defined and then you can do

```
<Upvote pin={pin ? pin.upvotes : defaultValue} userid={userid} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a ternary operator in Story before rendering Upvote as if `pin` is not present, Upvote won't render only.

Also, it will not break your code when `pin` is undefined.